# Scheduled Apex not consistantly executing, sending emails

Tags: apex, class, scheduled-apex, apex-email-service

I'm having a problem [similar to this user's question from about a year ago](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15003/scheduled-job-does-not-execute-though-shows-in-gui), although it's not clear to me whether the solution provided there actually resolved the issue (or if it just made the Salesforce UX better-represent the state of things on the Apex Jobs page).

I have a scheduled class that is intended run nightly. It will search through an object to find records where a custom checkbox = True, and then send an email with details about those records to an inbox for archiving. The schedulable class is as follows:

```
global class ScheduledArchiveProcess implements Schedulable {

    // Runs job every day at 11PM
    private static final String CRON_EXP = '0 0 23 * * ? *';

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        new CaseArchiveService().doArchive();
    }

    public static void setSchedule(String name) {
        System.schedule(name, CRON_EXP, new ScheduledArchiveProcess());
    }

    public static void setSchedule(String name, String cronExp) {
        System.schedule(name, cronExp, new ScheduledArchiveProcess());
    }
}
```

When I schedule the job (either via the UX or via the setSchedule methods above), it will not consistently send emails. I will setup test data and schedule the class, then nothing will happen for days. For whatever reason, several days into the schedule it will then choose to fire off the expected emails, but then will return to not consistently running. The Scheduled Jobs page implies it is running, but I have no emails to show for it.

I can directly run the code via Execute Anonymous and have the code consistently execute, so I don't think that's a problem (although given the number of records in the object we're querying, the SOQL query does take close to a minute to run when I submit via EA).

Given the scenario described above, I have the following questions:

1. Is there any known reason why a class would run inconsistently when scheduled, despite always running when directly invoked?
2. Would the solution documented in the [aforementioned question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15003/scheduled-job-does-not-execute-though-shows-in-gui) - aborting the current job, then rescheduling for a later time - actually address the problem I'm having, or would it just cause the Apex Jobs page to be more explicit about what has/has not been done?
3. Is there any way to add debugging to a scheduled job that is not being run under a specific user profile (or am I mistaken here and it *is* being run under a profile)?

I should note that I'm an Apex novice, working with code that was completed (but not turned on) before our previous developer departed, so apologies for any obvious misses or boneheaded statements. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

**Update 4/9/15:** I suspect this may have something to do with Salesforce timing out the query when initiated via a scheduled job. When I run it via the scheduler, I get up to the query and find the following:

```
14:00:20.936 (936955661)|METHOD_EXIT|[40]|01pF0000002QxZ2|ArchiveService.getObjectArchiveQuery()
14:00:20.936 (936987788)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[40]|Database.query(String)
14:00:20.940 (940831639)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[40]|Aggregations:0|SELECT [a whole bunch of fields] FROM Case WHERE needs_archive__c = true
14:02:24.902 (124902031857)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
```

However, when I run the same code via Execute Anonymous, it continues past this point:

```
13:51:44.034 (1034339365)|METHOD_EXIT|[40]|01pF0000002QxZ2|ArchiveService.getObjectArchiveQuery()
13:51:44.038 (1038006973)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[40]|Aggregations:0|SELECT [a whole bunch of fields] FROM Case WHERE needs_archive__c = true
13:53:07.150 (84150020438)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[40]|Rows:2
```

(I've omitted the SOQL SELECT for brevity - it's just grabbing a whole bunch of fields)

Comment: Have you tried logging a case with salesforce on this?

Comment: I have not yet; I was attempting to exhaust non-support research and resolution options first, just in case it was an issue that the community had already encountered and come up with good solutions for.

Comment: Curious if you ever got to the bottom of this, we are having a similar problem with both emails not being sent, and tasks not being created via scheduled apex. Suspect we've encountered the same thing.

Comment: @DavidGillen - we wound up having a ton of problems with this code beyond just this issue, so we ultimately wound up working around it by using a custom object as a worktable + Process Builder to create records on said worktable. However, I feel pretty confidant that the problem was that our Case object had too many records for the query to complete in a timely manner, and the scheduled apex was hitting a mystery limit and giving up. The custom object has way fewer records on it (and can get cleared on a regular basis) and the same query works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ultimately we got around it by having the scheduled apex call methods in a second class. The refactoring took not very long at all. Debug logs unfortunately were not showing up any problems with what we were trying to do, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Things to think about...

1. Since the scheduled job has to execute under some user, you can set up debug  log for that user and monitor for errors.
2. There is a limit on outbound Apex emails per day; perhaps some other job has exceeded the limit before the job in question has executed
3. There could be some query timeout or other catchable exception and the code as written doesn't fail gracefully

With the exception of limit exceptions, asynchronous code should use try-catch to ensure that every exception is caught and some diagnostic log is written for later examination. Such log could be an email to the sysad or and/or writing to a custom `Log__c` SObject a list of interesting things that happened during the course of execution. Dan Appleman's book 'Advanced Apex Programming' has a good debugging framework worth considering/adapting

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback! I think you're right that it may be a timeout of the query - once I got the logs set and reviewed some differences between what was happening when it was run via Scheduler vs. Execute Anonymous, I could see that the code was exiting after the query for the former, while pushing through and getting results for the latter (I added some notes to this effect to my original post in an update). I think we're OK on the email front, as we're sending to a User and not to an email address set in the Apex (and it isn't making it to the send step).

Comment: And thanks for the book recommendation! I'll check it out.